# Using an RSA Public Key generated by JavaScript from Java

Tags: java, coldfusion, cryptography, rsa

I've generated an RSA Keypair [from JavaScript](http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/javascript-asynchronous-rsa-key-generation) and now I want to use the public key in a Java app ([CFML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion), actually, but I'm directly using Java libs) to decrypt messages between the two.

After generating the keypair from JS the pubkey is transmitted to the server as a hex string. For example:

```
idliZFy2GQOwVoPHIlDlBSbJd9jFw7DPKzDfZnPOSo4pGpSjjvfyXQaBc+OCSLc3C6+H0XE02T0Bjd40RuGzhw==
```

Here's my code for attempting to use that hex string to hydrate an RSA public key object and use it to decrypt a ciphertext.

```
private function decryptPayload( payload, pubKey ){
    //adapted from:
    //  http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2010/7/19/Using-Asymmetric-Cryptography-in-your-ColdFusion-Application--Security-Series-1610
    var cipher = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.Cipher').getInstance("RSA");
    var decMode = cipher.DECRYPT_MODE;
    var returnStr = "";

    var pubkeyByteArray = BinaryDecode( pubKey, "Base64" );
    var specs = createObject("java","java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec").init( pubkeyByteArray );
    var inflated = createObject('java', 'java.security.KeyFactory').getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(specs);

    cipher.init( decMode, inflated );
    returnStr = cipher.doFinal( arguments.payload, 0, len(arguments.payload) );
    return toString(returnStr, "UTF8");
}
```

However, when I run this, passing the above hex string for the `pubKey` argument, I get the error **Invalid RSA public key encoding.** on the line:

```
var inflated = createObject('java', 'java.security.KeyFactory').getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(specs);
```

I get the feeling I'm just missing a step somewhere, but I don't know what to do. What am I missing or doing wrong?

---

Attempt with RSAPublicKeySpec suggestion from comments:

```
private function decryptPayload( payload, pubKey = 'jx7I6P0BoE+oIStMrtTx54D0QRhs69qQkdopthDGb4Ji4UzP/mZZEcnjfZjgQzZ9ciwU0fkCHmpS9K5CmQp34w==' ){
    //adapted from:
    //  http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2010/7/19/Using-Asymmetric-Cryptography-in-your-ColdFusion-Application--Security-Series-1610
    var cipher = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.Cipher').getInstance("RSA");
    var decMode = cipher.DECRYPT_MODE;
    var returnStr = "";

    var pubkeyByteArray = BinaryDecode( pubKey, "Base64" );
    var modulous = createObject('java','java.math.BigInteger').init(pubkeyByteArray);
    var exponent = createObject('java', 'java.math.BigInteger').init( "03", 16 );
    var keyspec = createObject('java', 'java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec').init( modulous, exponent );
    var inflated = createObject('java', 'java.security.KeyFactory').getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(keyspec);

    cipher.init( decMode, inflated );
    returnStr = cipher.doFinal( arguments.payload ); //, 0, len(arguments.payload)
    return toString(returnStr, "UTF8");
}

writeOutput(decryptPayload('59e948...59c3529b4fae61dd0a6e36'));
```

Here I am able to create a modulus `BigInt` from the hex value and an exponent `BigInt` from the known value "03", and feed those into `RSAPublicKeySpec`, and feed that resulting spec into my RSA `cipher` instance without issue.

Now I'm stuck on the `doFinal()` step because the method signature doesn't match. I'm attempting to pass it a string but it seems like it wants a byte array. I don't know exactly what I'm getting back from the JS encrypt() call, or how to convert that to a ByteArray.

Comment: How exactly is the pubkey transmitted to the server?

Comment: also, Adobe now recommend using BinaryDecode(data,"Base64") although the code you have also looks ok

Comment: @DanBracuk the pubkey is sent via HTTP over SSL.

Comment: @barnyr I just tried with BinaryDecode() and it didn't make a difference. I'm still getting the same error. But as it's the new recommendation I'll keep it in there. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an additional layer of encryption when you already have a secure communication channel (SSL)?

Comment: For this particular app we believe that additional peace of mind is worth the additional development effort and processing power. Some things are more sensitive than others; the data in this app included.

Comment: The java code expects the public key to be X509 encoded. Is it? (I barely skimmed the javascript article, so I am not sure what it returns)

Comment: I don't know for sure. I just searched all of the code and dependencies of the JS library and "x509" doesn't appear at all. I _can_ tell you that the example of exporting the pubkey takes it from a BigInteger, encodes that as hex, and then that as base64: `pubKey = hex2b64(key.n.toString(16))`. Does that help?

Comment: Also I've been digging and I think that the second argument for keypair generation is an "exponent." (The argument name in the code is `E` and some of the jsbn docs reference using an exponent of `"10001"` with openssl when testing interoperability). The example in the article uses `"03"` as the value when generating; but I've found I can change it without issue. I tried creating a keypair using `"10001"` and nothing changes server-side.

Comment: I am thinking it is not, because the code above works if you pass in X509 encoded bytes of a valid public key. If the library gives you access to the both the `modulus` and `publicExponent`, you could try using the [RSAPublicKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPublicKeySpec.html) constructor instead of X509Encoded..

Comment: I was able to create a modulus BigInt from the hex value and an exponent BigInt from the known value "03", and feed those into RSAPublicKeySpec, and feed that resulting spec into my RSA cipher instance without issue. (Appended a new section to the end of my question with this code). Now I'm stuck on the `doFinal` step because the signature doesn't match. I'm attempting to pass it a string but it seems like it wants a byte array. I don't know exactly what I'm getting back from the JS `encrypt()` call, or how to convert that to a ByteArray.

Comment: @ntoskrnl To answer your question, I have spoken with Adam extensively about this project, and the reason he is doing this is not for an extra layer of encryption. He is doing for data integrity and authenticity using RSA PKI to have the client sign the request before sending it to the server.  The added encryption is a bonus, but not the purpose.

Comment: @JasonDean SSL also supports client authentication – it might be easier and more secure to utilize the existing protocol.

Comment: I know that. But that is not practical on this type of application.

Comment: @AdamTuttle - Um.. are we are getting the keys backward? :) (Sorry I am a little distracted)

Comment: @AdamTuttle Yes, it wants a byteArray.  cipher.doFinal( binaryDecode( arguments.payload, "HEX" ) );

Comment: @Leigh No, his keys are not backward. He is supposed to be decrypting with the public key. But I think that he is also, inadvertently *encrypting* with the public key on the JavaScript side. We are working on that right now offline.

Comment: @JasonDean - Ah, okay good. (The reason I asked was that some of the js samples I looked at seemed to decrypt with the *private* key, rather than the public one. So I was not sure if they gotten reversed somehow .. or if I was just a bit brain dead yesterday ;)

Comment: @Leigh Encrypting with the public key and decrypting with the private key is the way we usually see it because that is the way it is done for hiding data, the confidentiality side of the crypto puzzle. Encrypting with the private key and decrypting with the public key is how to "sign" with PKI crypto, which is the integrity and authentication side of the crypto puzzle. This is less commonly done, hence, fewer examples. But that is what Adam is going for.

Comment: @JasonDean - Ohh, now it makes sense. I do not have a lot of experience with PKI, so I was wondering about some of the contradictory examples I saw yesterday... I was testing with [this code](http://pastebin.com/kfQ8QynS) (but plugging in the hex encoded JS values in place of the random java stuff at the top). Thanks for the explanation!